# "Is/Are there any more..."?

Tags: grammaire, questions, déterminants

If you want to say "Is there any more bread?", would you say "Est-ce qu'il y a aucun pain?". And similarly if you'd like to know if there is any more of something else but plural, such as "Are there any more available tickets?", would you say "Est-ce qu'il y a aucuns tickets disponibles?"

Whether or not the above constructions are grammatically correct, could you suggest other ways to ask these 2 questions?

Side note: I'm tempted to use the "ne...plus" construction because it means "anymore", but "any more" and "anymore" are different, which is why I don't think it would work. What's the verdict on this one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Your first sentence:

> Est-ce qu'il y a aucun pain ?

doesn't work. It somewhat means *Is there no bread?*

Possible ways to express what you are looking for are:

> Est-ce qu'il y a encore du pain ?
>   Y a-t-il encore du pain ?
>   Est-ce qu'il reste du pain?

Similarily:

> Est-ce qu'il y a encore des tickets disponibles ?
>   Y a-t-il encore des tickets disponibles ?
>   Est-ce qu'il reste des tickets ?

Comment: “Y a-t-il aucun pain” will sound incorrect nowadays, but I think long ago it might have been used (to be confirmed…).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Yes, in such case it would be equivalent to "*Y-a-t'il quelque pain ?*".

Comment: Le trait d'union entre *y* et *a* n'est pas requis, me semble-t-il.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Oui, bien sûr, corrigé.

Comment: Merci! Now I won't freeze every time I want to ask if a bakery has anymore mille feuille, haha!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to say it via a negative sentence, it will be:

> Est-ce qu'il n'y a plus de pain ?
>   N'y a-t-il plus de pain ?
>   Est-ce qu'il ne reste plus de pain ?

Otherwise, @jlliagre's examples are right.

Comment: Merci, la version negative c'est aussi très utile!